# detected and connect scanner barcode winson model WGI-311 in windows form c#

Tags: c#, windows, barcode

I have barcode scanner device
I want detect and connect this device in my application (windows form c#)
but ,I don't know how will be connect

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't to. Let me explain: your device (I think is USB) is already connected to windows, so it is working like another keyboard.
Just set the cursor to a textBox or whatever might accept entry if you are on windows Forms or use Console.ReadLine() if you use a console app.

```
// for a console app: example (you'll see the entry twice of course!)
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(inputCode);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When you run this, just scan a barcode and it will show the scanned string (twice: one for the keyboard, the other from the variable output).

For a Windows.Forms app, I suggest your code sets the focus to an empty field as a TextBox and you use its KeyDown event to test if a string has come in. Note that your scanner should be able to perform a CR or CR-LF at the end of the scan (this was also applicable to the console app example for the Console.ReadLine() to exit).

Here's an example: put 2 text boxes (textBox1 and textBox2) in your form.

```
    // This will give focus and place cursor on textBox2 at form start (normally, it would be on the first textBox created)
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.Select();
        textBox2.KeyDown += TextBox2_KeyDown;
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // This will copy to the textBox1 the incoming scanned barcode
            textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
        }
    }
```

Of course, these are only examples to show the flow. Don't use 2 text containers with the same content in real life!

After your first comment:
Put a listBox in your Form and a button to trigger this:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Keyboard");

        foreach (ManagementObject keyboard in searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (PropertyData prop in keyboard.Properties)
            {
                if (prop.Value != null)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(prop.Value);
                    // later, use: if (Convert.ToString(prop.Value).Contains("your device")) to check the presence
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Add this at the beggining:

```
using System.Management;
```

This will show you the devices connected to your computer. By plugging/unplugging, note the reference of the scanner (or the USB dongle), and later you can test if it is connected or not.

Please comment again if you need further help.

Comment: I need the code to first detect the USB barcode scanner and then scan a barcode and display it inside a text box on  windows form c# ...

Comment: Answer completed according to your comment, please note I already gave you the method to display it into a textBox: set just one textBox and use the key_down event to trigger what you want to do. If it is just display the codebar value, you have nothing more to do. Your device works like a keyboard.

Comment: I appreciate it ,thanks for your response

Comment: You're very welcome, Mohammad

Comment: I want when read qr code from scanner into textbox

Comment: Just put a textBox for that in your Form. Name it textBoxScan for example. Then, in the constructor of the form, right after << InitializeComponent(); >> type the line << 
 textBoxScan.Select(); >> to select and place the cursor in it. Lauch your program. When you press the read button of your scanner, it will send the digits in this textBox.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this work have delay for when read qr code from scanner

Comment: How much? I think this is due to hardware since the rest is implemented by the OS windows... the code is quasi non-existant, it's not the code that cause this delay (what is your processor?)

Comment: thanks for reply, my CPU is corei5,but very delay for read barcode or qr code in my application. what do I do?

Comment: At the moment, when I scan the barcode application on Windows, it is delayed and sometimes it does not scan the information at all. But the scanner sound is activated but does not send information to the text box. please help

Comment: How many seconds does it take? I'm very sorry but this does not come from the code but from the hardware OR the driver of this hardware. I suggest you scan the same way into NotePad.exe or try another mark/model if you can. (Your CPU is very good by the way)

Comment: @MohammadaminNajafi  Another idea: I could see the model on alibaba website. But I can't say if it is a wireless device. If it is wireless, it has a USB dongle. Then, try to change the port where you connect this device because there might be interferences (and that's where you have the troubles you describe).

Comment: Thanks for your good answers, it has good speed now and the barcode is easily scanned